# How to show there is no sequence of nonnegative integers that satisfies $2^{i+2}-2+x_{i+1} \leq 2x_i$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_i\}$ be a sequence of integers greater or equal to zero satisfying the following inequality: $2^{i+2}-2+x_{i+1} \leq 2x_i$. I have tried to construct such a sequence but failed. Can you prove that such sequence does not exist?

Comment: @Saad I was not faking the context. I was describing something that I did. Furthermore,  suppose I would like to ask the same problem. What could I do? Asking a new question and link to this one? Or just be content with this question in a state of being closed?

Comment: [Editing someone else's question to add context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21106/editing-someone-elses-question-to-add-context)

Comment: @Apass.Jack That post is quite old.  The current policy is at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32402/ .

Answer (score 3):

Let $y_i=i2^{i+1}+2+x_i$ for all $i\ge1$.

$$\begin{aligned}
y_{i+1}
&=(i+1)2^{i+2}+2+x_{i+1}\\
&=i\,2^{i+2}+ 4+ (2^{i+2}-2+x_{i+1})\\
&\le2\,i\,2^{i+1}+ 4+ 2\,x_i\\
&=2y_i
\end{aligned}$$

Hence $y_i\le 2^{i-1}y_1$ for all $i\ge1$ by straightforward induction.

However $y_i=i2^{i+1}+2+x_i> 2^{i-1}y_1$ when $i\ge \frac{y_1}{2^2}$.
This contradiction implies there is no such sequence.

---

The proof above does not use the condition that the numbers in the sequence are integers.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to see this by using telescoping series.

The inequality is equivalent to
$$
\frac{x_{i+1}}{2^{i+1}} - \frac{x_i}{2^i} \leqslant \frac1{2^i} - 2,
$$
which implies that for all $i \geqslant 1,$
$$
\frac{x_i}{2^i} - \frac{x_1}{2} \leqslant
\left(\frac12 + \cdots + \frac1{2^{i-1}}\right) - 2i + 2 < 3 - 2i,
$$
whence
$$
x_i < 0 \text{ for all }i \geqslant \frac{\frac{x_1}2 + 3}2.
$$
As already remarked in @apass-jack's answer, it is not necessary to assume that the $x_i$ are integers.